# Has the term "Hit the bricks" ever meant "go to bed"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I am from Iowa and I have heard the term "Hit the bricks" used in the same way as "hit the sack" or "hit the hay" in terms of going to bed.  Recently a friend from Colorado and I were discussing this phrase and he remembers it being used the same way.  Was it ever used in this fashion?

Comment: I've heard it used for what I took to mean "hit the streets".

Comment: I have only ever heard it to mean "Hit the Road" as in *Leave*, *Escape* or *Take a Powder*. Think Yellow Brick Road, and *Take a hike, Dorothy!*"

Comment: Well you have anecdotal evidence from two people that it *was* used that way, but I've never heard it used like that, and I wouldn't think it was a common usage because who would want to sleep on bricks?

Comment: It doesn’t seem likely.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. See https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hit+the+bricks / https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hit_the_bricks